# How to let browser to trust self-generated SSL certificates on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, ssl, browser, ssl-certificate

I added the certificate to Trusted Root Certifications Authorities in Windows, using the MMC Certificate snap-in:

[image]

But when I navigate to the page, I still the warning that there is a problem with the certificate.

On Firefox, there is an option to Add an Exception. On Chrome and IE, there is none.

[image]

How do I stop browsers from giving these warnings and just load the https page ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)

Comment: "On Firefox, there is an option to Add an Exception. On Chrome and IE, there is none." - so how do the dialogs look like on IE and Chrome? Apart from that Firefox does not use the Windows trust store but uses its own, i.e. any certificates need to be added there too.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite: no the solution in that answer did not work. And my question involves IE and FF as well.

Comment: Its not a trust issue, the error shows that the *common name* in the certificate is not correct and does not match the host.  Regenerate the certificate with the correct name and import it in to the trusted CA store.

Comment: @AlexK. : Can you explain which host name are you referring to ? In IIS Manager Creating self-signed certificate, I only see "Specify Friendly Name :http://imgur.com/a/Y1L3m

Comment: @AlexK  any idea how to give the correct name for the cert ?